# How do I change this Table from horizontal to vertical

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I try to visualize a List> but when it comes to changing the orientation of my table, I have no clue how to do this.

Table Now:

```
list1a list1b list1c
list2a list2b
list3a list3b list3c
```

what I need:

```
list1a list2a list3a
list1b list2b list3b
list1c        list3c
```

what I get by changing the stackpannel orientation to vertical:

```
list1a
list1b
list1c
list2a
list2b
list3a
list3b
list3c
```

My Xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level2">
        <Grid Height="26" Width="120">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" Margin="4" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level1">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level2}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="tbParts" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level1}" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Edit:

Population of my Table-Model:

```
List<string> nodes = GetNodes()
List<List<Part>> table = new List<List<Part>>();
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
{ TestOutput.table.Add(new List<Part>(parts.Where(x => x.techRequired == nodes[i]).ToList())); }
```

Comment: Yeah, you just need to form your data into the correct shape, by iterating through each row and populating a different collection as you go.

Comment: what I do now to populate my List<List<Part>> is for(int i = 0; i < nodes.Count;i++) {table.Add(new List<Part>(parts.Where(x => x.techRequired == nodes[i]).ToList()));} I am realy not sure, how i should change the direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you've posted I presume you have two ItemsControls nested. The first ItemControl should have a StackPanel with Orientation = Horizontal nope ? Then the inner ItemsControls should be Orientation = Vertical. I'll be clearer with some code :-) :

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level2">
        <Grid Height="26" Width="120">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" Margin="4" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level1">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level2}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="tbParts" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level1}">
         <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
         </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```